$f((x,y))=(x*gcd(x,y),y) $is injective and surjective?
The function $f:\mathbb{N^+}\times\mathbb{N^+} \rightarrow \mathbb{N^+}\times\mathbb{N^+} $ definide as $f((x,y))=(x*gcd(x,y),y) $is injective and surjective?
Let $(a,b)\in\mathbb{N^+}\times\mathbb{N^+}$
I want $(x,y)$ such that $f((x,y))=(a,b)$.
Of course y must be equal to b.

if $gcd(a,b)=1$ then $f((a,b))=(a * gcd(a,b)=a,b)$
if $x$ is such that $x * gcd(x,y)=x * gcd(x,b)=a$, then I can write $x=d*\hat{x}$ where $d=gcd(x,b)$.
So I have $\hat{x}*d^2 = a$ i.e. $d^2\mid a$, $d\mid b$.
So f is not surjective, for example for $(10,8)$ we can't find a solution.

Now f is injective if $f((x,y))=f((\hat{x},\hat{y}))\rightarrow x=\hat{x}$ and $y=\hat{y}$.
Of course $\hat{y}=y$ But I don't know how to prove if $x=\hat{x}$.
Maybe I'm missing something...

Hint: Look at how often the numbers are divisible by a prime $p$.
If $y$ is divisible $b$ times and $x$ is divisible $a$ times, then $\mathrm{gcd}(x,y)$ is divisible $\min\{a,b\}$ times and the result is divisible $a+\min\{a,b\}$ times. Since this is injective for fixed $b$ (why?),  $x$ and $\hat x$ are divisible by $p$ the same number of times.
Since this holds for all $p$, $x=\hat x$.

So if $a=p^\alpha_1 * q_1$ $x * gcd(x,b) = a = p^{\alpha_1}* q_1$. Now if $x_1 $ is the number of times that $p \mid x$  and $\beta$ is the number of times that $p \mid b$, $x_1 +min{x_1,\beta}=\alpha_1$. Now I have 2 cases: -1 $\beta > \frac{\alpha}{2}$ then $x_1+x_1=\alpha_1$ -2 $\beta < \frac{\alpha}{2}$ then $x_1=\alpha_1 - \beta$. In every case $x_1$ is fixed and since this holds for all p, x=\hat{x}. Is that right?

Yes, although I needed a bit of time to understand your notation.

Thanks, I will improve my writing.
